# How to configure tomcat for a subdirectory of jsp files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a java web application package under public_html using a commercial product CPanel. My java source code is under WEB-INF/classes/. My jsp files are under public_html and public_html/version/v1. Now all of my jsp file under public_html are running fine, however, the jsp files under public_html/version/v1 do not work with following error:

HTTP Status 500: Unable to compile for class JSP: 
type Exception report 
message Unable to compile class for JSP: 
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp 
Utility cannot be resolved to a type

Utility is one of my java file under WEB-INF/classes.

It looks like there is a problem with tomcat configuration of either server.xml or web.xml. Can anybody help me to make the jsp files under public_html/version/v1/index.jsp work?

If you are using TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, that would be fine. You may let me know how to configure tomcat for a subdirectory of JSP files under your settings.

The content of my JSP is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.util.Random, java.io.*,java.lang.*,java.sql.*,java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page language="java"  import="com.blueworld.pac.*" %>
<%

try{
Utility u = new Utility();
u.ReadProps();
String jspURL=u.jspPath;
String special_req=request.getParameter("special");
System.out.println(special_req);
} catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
%>
```

My classes files are under WEB-INF/classes/com/blueworld/pac/.

Comment: Provide the content of your JSP.

Comment: You state that your classes are in WEB-INF/classes, but not if your Utility class is actually in the package com.blueworld.pac - e.g. do you have a WEB-INF/classes/com/blueworld/pac/Utility.class file in your web application?

Comment: What happens if you reference `Utility` fully qualified: `com.blueworld.pac.Utility u = new com.blueworld.pac.Utility();`  ?